# Assigning CA SSL certificate to SOLR

Tags: solr, certificate

We are trying to install SOLR in a standalone server for a production environment. A client has already installed an SSL server certificate on the Server. I can see it in

> MMC->Certificates->Personal && MMC->Certificates->Trusted Root
>   Certificates.

Not sure how to assign this to SOLR?

I have previously created self-signed SSL for SOLR in development machine and assigned to localhost successfully by adding below parameters to solr.in.cmd

```
set SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE=etc/solr-ssl.keystore.jks
set SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD=secret
set SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE=etc/solr-ssl.keystore.jks
set SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD=secret
```

But not sure how to generate jks file and password for already installed CA certificate, could someone have done this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33617420/is-it-possible-to-use-solr-with-ssl-and-ca-signed-certs), it should be possible using the same steps, but skipping the generation parts.

> The Java truststore and keystore files are the same regardless if its
>   self-signed or CA-signed certificates.
>
> Using the instructions from your CA, import the appropriate
>   certificates to the truststore and keystore that Solr will use, and
>   then configure your Solr to point to your new truststore/keystore
>   files (and required passwords to access the certificates).
>
> In other words, follow the instructions you linked, just skip the
>   first step (Generate a self-signed certificate and a key), the rest of
>   the instructions are still valid, even with your CA-signed
>   certificates.